# Returning queryset.values() from viewset.get_queryset()?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Good day,

I'm having difficulty trying to return `queryset.values()` from a viewset's `get_queryset()`. After finding 6 different methods for allegedly dealing with this, I am still left uncertain how to manage it *correctly* as my only working solution feels hacky.

I use `values` so that I can get the name of the UserAccount through the foreign-key, rather than it's id. I tried using `only()` (replacing `values()` with it), but it doesn't seem to do anything. The end goal is for any user to be be able to get comments and see the names of all the commenters, rather than their ID.

---

**ViewSet**

```python
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = serializers.CommentSerializer
    queryset = models.Comment.objects.all()
    lookup_field='comment_id'

    # A. This works, but I don't want to define extra actions if I don't have to.
    @action(detail=False, url_path='use-user-name')
    def use_user_name(self, request, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns the user's name rather than its id.
        """
        return Response(self.queryset.values('comment_id', 'operator_id__name', 'dlc', 'comment'))

    # B. This doesn't work.
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.values('comment_id', 'operator_id__name', 'dlc', 'comment')

    # C. Nor does this.
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset.values('comment_id', 'operator_id__name', 'dlc', 'comment')
        return json.dumps(list(queryset), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

    # D. Nor this.
    def get_queryset(self):
        return serializers.serialize('json', list(self.queryset), fields=('comment_id', 'operator_id__name', 'dlc', 'comment'))

    # E. Nor this.
    def get_queryset(self):
        return list(self.queryset.values('comment_id', 'operator_id__name', 'dlc', 'comment'))

    # F. Nor this.
    def get_queryset(self):
        return json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', queryset=self.queryset))
```

---

**Models and Serializers**

```python
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='comment_id')
    operator_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='operator_id')
    dlc = models.DateTimeField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'comment'


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Comment
        fields = ('__all__')


# What is defined in "settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL".
class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
```

---

**Errors Raised**

Options *B* and *E* produces this error:

```python
  ...
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 273, in to_representation
    return value.pk
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Options *C* and *D* produce this error:

```python
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `dlc` on serializer `CommentSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'dlc'.
```

Option *F* produces this error:

```python
KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `dlc` on serializer `CommentSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'dlc'."
```

---

**Output**

The following are examples of what would be returned from `get_queryset()`.

```
# Options A and B produce this:
<QuerySet [
    {'comment_id': 1, 'operator_id__name': 'John Smith', 'dlc': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 3, 20, 48, 48), 'comment': 'First comment.'},
    {'comment_id': 2, 'operator_id__name': 'Jill Green', 'dlc': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 3, 20, 48, 49), 'comment': 'Second comment.'}
]>

# C produces this:
[
    {"comment_id": 1, "operator_id__name": "John Smith", "dlc": "2022-04-03T20:48:48", "comment": "First comment."},
    {"comment_id": 2, "operator_id__name": "Jill Green", "dlc": "2022-04-03T20:48:49", "comment": "Second comment."}
]

# Options D and F produce this (note - missing "operator_id__name"):
[
    {"model": "test.comment", "pk": 1, "fields": {"dlc": "2022-04-03T20:48:48", "comment": "First comment."}},
    {"model": "test.comment", "pk": 2, "fields": {"dlc": "2022-04-03T20:48:49", "comment": "Second comment."}}
]

# E produces this:
[
    {'comment_id': 1, 'operator_id__name': 'John Smith', 'dlc': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 3, 20, 48, 48), 'comment': 'First comment.'},
    {'comment_id': 2, 'operator_id__name': 'Jill Green', 'dlc': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 3, 20, 48, 49), 'comment': 'Second comment.'}
]
```

---

Given the relationship between these two models, what is the best way to get the `Comment` fields with the `operator_id__name` swapped in for the `operator_id`?

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you for taking the time to read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializers can access the related fields via the source argument.

```
name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='operator_id.name')
```

and then to avoid n+1 problem, in your queryset

```
return super().get_queryset().select_related("operator_id")
```

---

Other than this, there are several possible mistakes in your code.

- Is there a reason why your models are not managed?
- models.DO_NOTHING is extremely bad unless you have database triggers or constraints in place. In which case you probably should comment them into the code so the next person doesn't warn about it.
- Django relation fields already append `_id` to end of the fields, so if this is model is hand-written and not generated you should just call a field `relation = ForeignKey()` and not `relation_id = ForeignKey()`. Disregard this if the db is not managed by django.
- It's mostly best to avoid `__all__` unless you know that there won't be any other field added to the model that may not want to be exposed to public.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
views.py

class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = serializers.CommentSerializer
    queryset = models.Comment.objects.all()
```

```
serializers.py

class UserAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """UserAccount model serializer"""
    class Meta(object):
        model = UserAccount
        fields = ("id", "email", "name",)
        read_only_fields = ("id", "email", "name",)


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Comment model serializer"""
    operator_id = UserAccountSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta(object):
        model = Comment
        fields = ("comment_id", "operator_id", "dlc",)
        read_only_fields = ("comment_id",)
```

or

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Comment model serializer"""

    class Meta(object):
        model = Comment
        fields = ("comment_id", "operator_id", "dlc",)
        read_only_fields = ("comment_id",)

    def to_representation(self, instance):

        return {
            "comment_id": instance.id,
            "operator_id__name": instance.operator_id.name,
            "dlc" : instance.dlc
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. These suggestions would not return the `operator_id__name`, nor would they return the comments of any user other than the one making the request. I have edited the question to provide that missing clarification. It isn't enough to just get the current user's comments, I would like to map all comments to the names of the commenters.

Comment: I think this answer has been updated, and I think it's work.